# How to connect to OpenVPN GUI with AutoHotKey

Tags: windows, openvpn, automation, autohotkey, hotkeys

I've been using the OpenVPN GUI with an `.ovpn` file (I use the one provided by free VPN [SigaVPN](https://sigavpn.com/)) for about a year, and although I'm generally pleased with both OpenVPN and SigaVPN, it's getting tiring to connect manually. I'm trying to automate this process in the usual way with AutoHotKey, using my numpad's 5/Clear key:

```
NumpadClear::
Run C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe --connect 1529624602320169353.ovpn
Return
```

But running this only serves to opens the OpenVPN GUI client itself, and forces me to continue connecting to the VPN manually.

Alternatively, providing the `.ovpn` file's full path:

```
NumpadClear::
Run C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe --connect "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\1529624602320169353.ovpn"
Return
```

...fails with some variation of the following error:

[image]

What's causing this, and exactly how can I automatically connect to my VPN with AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has two causes: AutoHotKey not being in the right directory to run the `.ovpn` file, and the OpenVPN GUI client having no support for providing the full path to the `.ovpn` file as part of the `--connect` option.

As the result, the solution is to navigate AHK to the directory which contains the `.ovpn` file and to run the script directly from that directory. This can be accomplished by using AHK's `SetWorkingDir` function:

```
NumpadClear::
SetWorkingDir, C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config 
Run C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe --connect 1529624602320169353.ovpn
Return
```

Note the peculiar AHK syntax of separating the function from the parameter with a comma, and remember to change the path here to reflect the one which contains your own `.opvn` file.